# Connecting Kovri through a VPN vs using Kovri directly

Tags: security, privacy, kovri, i2p, vpn

In terms of privacy and security what are the differences between to connecting Kovri through a VPN compared running Kovri directly?

Would home, business or VPS IP addresses be better protected if a VPN is used to connect Kovri?

Would VPNs be able to tell that someone is using Monero or that someone is using Kovri/I2P?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using Kovri alone, the ISP/your employer/whoever is able to see that you are using Kovri, but not what you're doing on Kovri (e.g. using Monero).

When using Kovri with a VPN, the ISP will just be able to see that you're connecting to a VPN. However the VPN provider and their ISP will be able to see that you're connecting to Kovri.

Personally I think that it's better to use Kovri alone, but if you're feeling extra paranoid and want to use a VPN, the only harm would be some increased latency and decreased speeds.